# Can't find out how to backtest Pine script strategy on trading view

Tags: pine-script, tradingview-api

I am looking to find out how to backtest this strategy on trading view that is written in pine script

`// This source code is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public License 2.0 at` [`https://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/`](https://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/)
`//@version=5`
`strategy('Buy or Sell Signal', overlay=true)`

`//inputs`
`Source = input(hl2, title='Source')`
`Multiplier = input.float(title='ATR Multiplier', step=0.1, defval=3.0)`

`//Compute ATR Levels`
`atr = ta.atr(input(title='ATR Period', defval=10))`

`//Creating Upper Channel`
`up = Source - Multiplier * atr`
`up1 = nz(up[1], up)`
`up := close[1] > up1 ? math.max(up, up1) : up`

`//Creating Down Channel`
`dn = Source + Multiplier * atr`
`dn1 = nz(dn[1], dn)`
`dn := close[1] < dn1 ? math.min(dn, dn1) : dn`

`//Compute the Trend Stream +1/-1`
`trend = 1`
`trend := nz(trend[1], trend)`
`trend := trend == -1 and close > dn1 ? 1 : trend == 1 and close < up1 ? -1 : trend`

`//Create Stoploss for Longs`
`upPlot = plot(trend == 1 ? up : na, title='Up Trend', style=plot.style_linebr, linewidth=2, color=color.new(color.green, 0))`

`//Buy Signal`
`Buy = trend == 1 and trend[1] == -1`

`plotshape(Buy ? up : na, title='Go Long', location=location.absolute, style=shape.circle, size=size.tiny, color=color.new(color.green, 0))`
`plotshape(Buy ? up : na, title='Buy', text='Buy', location=location.absolute, style=shape.labelup, size=size.tiny, color=color.new(color.green, 0), textcolor=color.new(color.white, 0))`

`dnPlot = plot(trend == 1 ? na : dn, title='Down Trend', style=plot.style_linebr, linewidth=2, color=color.new(color.red, 0))`

`//Sell Signal`
`Sell = trend == -1 and trend[1] == 1`

`plotshape(Sell ? dn : na, title='Go Short', location=location.absolute, style=shape.circle, size=size.tiny, color=color.rgb(255, 82, 82, 10))`
`plotshape(Sell ? dn : na, title='Sell', text='Sell', location=location.absolute, style=shape.labeldown, size=size.tiny, color=color.rgb(255, 82, 82, 6), textcolor=color.new(color.white, 0))`

`iPlot = plot(ohlc4, title='', style=plot.style_circles, linewidth=0)`

`longFillColor = trend == 1 ? color.rgb(76, 175, 79, 90) : color.rgb(255, 255, 255, 11)`
`shortFillColor = trend == -1 ? color.rgb(255, 82, 82, 90) : color.rgb(255, 255, 255, 11)`

`fill(iPlot, upPlot, title='UpTrend Highligter', color=longFillColor)`
`fill(iPlot, dnPlot, title='DownTrend Highligter', color=shortFillColor)`

`//Alerts`
`alertcondition(Buy, title='SuperTrend Buy', message='SuperTrend Buy!')`
`alertcondition(Sell, title='SuperTrend Sell', message='SuperTrend Sell!')`

`buycontiue = ta.barssince(Sell) > ta.barssince(Buy)`
`sellcontinue = ta.barssince(Buy) > ta.barssince(Sell)`

`color = buycontiue[1] ? color.green : sellcontinue ? color.red : na`
`barcolor(color)`

I `have` been trying to figure this out and have no idea. Is anyone here that has some suggestion on how to fix this issue, such that I would be able to backtest this strategy ?

Comment: To backtest a strategy you have to introduce strategy-specific commands - `strategy.entry/exit/close` etc and the script you showed just plots labels and lines on the chart.

Answer (score 1):

Use [strategy.order](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#fun_strategy%7Bdot%7Dorder) with your *Buy* and *Sell* signals

Something like that:

```
if Buy
    strategy.order('Long', strategy.long)
if Sell
    strategy.order('Short', strategy.short)
```

**Note:**
*alertcondition()* has no effect inside strategies.